# Encode raw data from microphone SampleData event with actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I get a raw data from Microphone's SampleDataEvent, and I want to encode this data before streaming to my server. So I'd like to know if there any standard audio encoder provided in actionscript3? Or do I have to implement it myself?

I know that the Microphone class provide 2 codec (Nellymoser and Speex) that can be used when sending a stream to Flash Media Server( via NetStream) only. Is there any way we use this codec to encode raw data ?

Thank you,
Voteforpedro

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, it is already encoded.  The default codec used is Nellymoser.  You can change it by changing the codec field in Microphone